# Adding user input to Emails causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I'm creating an application that takes some user input via EditText and Checkbox and puts them into the subject and body of an email.

Whenever I run and try to set the subject in the try block, my emails do not send and I get those LogCat errors.

```
     public void sendEmails() {
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    String subject = "Maintenance Request";
            CheckBox main = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
              CheckBox kitchen = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
              CheckBox bathroom = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
              CheckBox other = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);


    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String username = "user@gmail.com";
    String password = "pwd";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

     session.setDebug(true);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
      MimeMessage msg1 = new MimeMessage(session);

         try {
              if (main.isChecked()) {
                    subject = subject + " - Main Room";
                }
                if (kitchen.isChecked()) {
                    subject = subject + " - Kitchen";
                }
                if (bathroom.isChecked()) {
                    subject = subject + " - Bathroom";
                }
                if (other.isChecked()) {
                    subject = subject + " - Other";
                }
                return subject;

                }
           msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
           msg1.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
           msg.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
           msg1.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(manager));
           msg.setSubject("Maintenance Confirmation");
           msg1.setSubject(subject);
           msg.setText("Some really important stuff. Confirmed.");
           msg1.setText("Really important stuff needs attention");
           props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
           props.put("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
           Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
           try {
               t.connect(host, username, password);
               t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
               t.sendMessage(msg1, msg1.getAllRecipients());
           }
           finally {
               t.close();
         } }  
         catch(Exception exc){
             exc.printStackTrace();
         }
        return null;
         }}.execute(); }
```

And on a button click this runs and calls the code

```
public void buttonclick3(View v) {
    //first extract text for EditText and convert to String
    EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
    String email = e.getText().toString();
    //run validateEmail on String and show alert if format is invalid
    if (validateEmail(email) == false) {
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setMessage("Please enter a valid Email address.");
         builder.setTitle("Invalid Input!");
         builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });
     builder.show();
    }
    else {
        //the email address is valid, send the emails
        sendEmails();
    }
```

I know the code is good because if I hard code the subject and don't call the method the emails send fine.

EDIT: Here is the LogCat. The application no longer crashes on the final button press, but the emails do not send and I get these errors in yellow in the LogCat, not red. Can anyone make sense of what my threads are doing and offer a solution?

- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): java.lang.NullPointerException
- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): at com.example.maintenanceapp.lastpage$1.doInBackground(lastpage.java:79)
- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): at com.example.maintenanceapp.lastpage$1.doInBackground(lastpage.java:1)
- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): atandroid.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
- 04-14 11:16:34.532: W/System.err(14378): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
- 04-14 11:16:34.537: W/System.err(14378): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Can you indicate which is line 79 in lastpage.java? Also can you tell me when you're finished editing because if this current revision is your code I can see clearly what the problem is...

Comment: This is my most current version as I play with it to find the error. Line 79 on lastpage.java is "if (main.isChecked()) {"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you're trying to access the UI in the `AsyncTask` background thread. This thread cannot access the UI thread and could easily cause a problem like this.

You need to move all code related to the UI from the `doInBackground()` method to another method override of `AsyncTask` such as the `onPreExecute()` method **alternatively you could move it to before the task is run** for the same result. For example:

```
private String subject = "Maintenance Request";

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    CheckBox main = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    CheckBox kitchen = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    CheckBox bathroom = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    CheckBox other = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

    if (main.isChecked()) subject = subject + " - Main Room";
    if (kitchen.isChecked()) subject = subject + " - Kitchen";
    if (bathroom.isChecked()) subject = subject + " - Bathroom";
    if (other.isChecked()) subject = subject + " - Other";

}
```

Or you could move it to before the `sendEmails();` line in your `buttonclick3()` method.

It doesn't send the email because the error occurs and further execution of the code in the try/catch is terminated before the email can be sent.

You should also consider learning more about AsyncTask, I found this to be very informative: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer to the original question:
This could be happening because you have defined your `subject` variable in a separate method and the `subject` variable is therefore out of scope. Your `setSubject()` method returns the value of the `subject` variable however, so to fix this you can remove the `setSubject()` method call from the click listener and change this line:

```
msg1.setSubject(subject);
```

To this:

```
msg1.setSubject(setSubject());
```

Comment: I tried that too, unfortunately I get the exact same error.

Comment: I also tried creating a string called String someSubject = setSubject(); and then setting msg1.setSubject(someSubject); and got the same error.

Comment: OK no worries, you should probably update your post to say that this is one of the things you've tried. I can't see anything else obviously wrong with this code, although there is clearly a lot of code missing, part of which could be causing this problem. You perhaps need to post the full contents of your activity XML and java files in order for anyone to be able to make sense of this issue. Also your LogCat looks like there should be more to it maybe. I will update my answer if you can provide this additional info and if I can find the source of the problem for you.

Comment: I see the logic here and in theory should work. But now I am faced with a problem of getting a String variable from that method. As you can see and know onPreExecute has to be type void so I can't return a String. I tried setting up the setSubject() method again to return a String and calling it in onPreExecute but this takes it out of scope from my doInBackground and can't set it to the subject.

Comment: Well the doInBackground function can still access properties of your activity class assuming your AsyncTask class is a subclass of the activity class. So you should have defined the subject variable as a property of the activity class e.g. private String subject = ""; at the start of the activity class and it would be within scope. If this is still causing problems you could just move this code from onPreExecute to before the task is run as mentioned in the answer.